# How to make a webpage fade in and fade out without it instantly fading in (Using JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make it to where there is a clean fade in and out transition between the multiple HTML pages within my website. I am trying to achieve this by causing everything but the navbar in my body to fade out, and then having that part fade back in. The Fadeout portion works fine, but, when I try to fade back in, the other pages' content instantly appears instead of gradually appearing.

The Javascript:

```
$("#MainBody").css('display','none');
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#MainBody").fadeIn('slow',function(){

    });
    jQuery("a").on('click',function(event){
        var thetarget = this.getAttribute('target')
        if(thetarget != "_blank"){
            var thehref = this.getAttribute('href')
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery("#MainBody").fadeOut('slow',function(){
                window.location =thehref;
                $("#MainBody").fadeIn('slow', function(){

                })
            });
        }
    });
});
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#MainBody').fadeIn();},1000);
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hakim Ottey's Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,300;1,200;1,400;1,700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="Header">
        <div class="Introduction">
            <div class="Intro_Info">
                <h1 class="Name">Hakim Ottey</h1>
                <h2 class="Title">Game Designer</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Resume">
            <h2 class="Download">Download Resume</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="Nav_Menu">
            <a href="index.html" class="Navi">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">Home</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="GD_Projects.html" class="Navi">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">Game Design Projects</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="Prog_Projects.html" class="Navi">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">Programming Projects</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="3DG_Art.html" class="Navi">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">3D Game Art</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="2DG_Art.html" class="Navi">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">2D Game Art</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="About_Me.html" class="Navi">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">About Me</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="Contacts.html" class="Navi">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">Contacts</li>
                </div>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="MainBody">
        <div class="General_Showcase">
            <div class="General_Info">
                <!-- first row -->
                <ul class="InfoRow">
                    <li class="infoinline">
                        <div class="showcase">
                            <div class="Info">
                                <h3>Experience</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="list_head">
                                        <h4>AI Programmer for robot development</h4>
                                    </li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="list_entry">Created contour recognition for robot​</li>
                                        <li class="list_entry"> Managed group milestones and needs </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <li class="list_head">
                                        <h4>Co-Lead and programmer for Project Techno </h4>
                                    </li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="list_entry">Programmed Loading and Character Select Menu​</li>
                                        <li class="list_entry">Re-worked vehicle functionality </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <li class="list_head">
                                        <h4>Programmer for InternMe App</h4>
                                    </li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="list_entry">Developed Wireframes for app​</li>
                                        <li class="list_entry">Programmed screen transitioning and basic functionality
                                            for
                                            the app
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="infoinline">
                        <div class="showcase">
                            <div class="Info">
                                <h3>Skills</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">2D Asset Creation</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">3d Asset Creation</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Test Suite Creation</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Programming in C++, C#, Python, Dart, XAML, and Java
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Website Development</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Unity Engine Development</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Unreal Engine Development</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Chatbot Development</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">App Development</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">AI Development</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="infoinline">
                        <div class="small_box">
                            <div class="topspace">
                            </div>
                            <div class="Info">
                                <img class="sm_images" src="Images/Cirlce_Overhead_PNG.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="infoinline">
                        <div class="showcase">
                            <div class="topspace">
                            </div>
                            <div class="Info">
                                <img class="images" src="Images/HO_Wall.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- second row -->
                <ul class="InfoRow">
                    <li class="infoinline">
                        <div class="showcase">
                            <div class="Info">
                                <h3>Program Experience</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Microsoft Visual Studio</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Microsoft Access</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">PHPMyAdmin</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Adobe Photoshop</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Adobe Illustrator</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Adobe Premiere</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Autodesk 3DSMax</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Autodesk Maya</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Unity Engine</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Unreal Engine</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Valve Hammer Editor</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="infoinline">
                        <div class="showcase">
                            <div class="Info">
                                <h3>Languages</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">HTML</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">CSS</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">C#</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">UnityScript</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Python</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Dart</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">XAML</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Java</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="infoinline">
                        <div class="small_box">
                            <div class="Info">
                                <h3>Engines</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Construct</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Unreal Engine</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Unity Engine</li>
                                    <li class="single_list_entry">Valve Hammer Editor</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="infoinline">
                        <div class="showcase">
                            <div class="Info">
                                <div class="topspace">
                                </div>
                                <iframe class="images" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XaqywWdpW4k" frameborder="0"
                                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Footer">
        <p class="footinfo">Hakim Ottey © 2019</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is an example of what the other pages have as content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game Design Projects | Hakim Ottey's Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,300;1,200;1,400;1,700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="Header">
        <div class="Introduction">
            <div class="Intro_Info">
                <h1 class="Name">Hakim Ottey</h1>
                <h2 class="Title">Game Designer</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Resume">
            <h2 class="Download">Download Resume</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="Nav_Menu">
            <a href="index.html" id="Home">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">Home</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="GD_Projects.html" id="GDP">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">Game Design Projects</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="Prog_Projects.html" id="PP">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">Programming Projects</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="3DG_Art.html" id="3DGA">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">3D Game Art</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="2DG_Art.html" id="2DGA">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">2D Game Art</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="About_Me.html" id="AboutMe">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">About Me</li>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="Contacts.html" id="Contacts">
                <div class="inlineNav">
                    <li class="navbutton">Contacts</li>
                </div>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="MainBody">
        <div class="Table_of_Contents">
            <div>
                <h3>Contents</h3>
            </div>
            <a href="" id="Adaptchar">
                <div class="PageLink">
                    <p>Adaptchar</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="" id="PageLink">
                <div class="PageLink">
                    <p>Project Techno</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="" id="P2CM">
                <div class="PageLink">
                    <p>Portal 2 Custom Map</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="" id="Unreal">
                <div class="PageLink">
                    <p>Unreal Target Test</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="" id="RBA">
                <div class="PageLink">
                    <p>Rockstar Bully Analysis</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="" i="CM">
                <div class="PageLink">
                    <p>Card Mechanics</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="GDBody">
            <div class="Portblock">
                <div class="PortPres">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Adaptchar</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortPicBox">
                        <iframe class="PortPic" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CBCdtNp6UU0" frameborder="0"
                            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="PortInfo">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Info on Adaptchar</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortExpl">
                        <p>By using Adaptchar, players playing role-playing games will be able to have their party grow
                            and
                            adapt to
                            how the
                            player wants to play the game. Using an Artificial Neural Network, players could either play
                            normally or
                            configure the weights of the ANN in order to teach the bots to make decisions that can
                            benefit
                            how
                            the
                            player
                            playstyle.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=Portblock>
                <div class="PortPres">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Project Techno</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortPicBox">
                        <iframe class="PortPic" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GxmuPkdXDzA" frameborder="0"
                            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="PortInfo">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Info on Project Techno</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortExpl">
                        <p>Worked with the lead of Project Techno to develop the loading screen, the UI for the
                            Character
                            Select and
                            End of
                            Level Screens, and functionality of the game's main vehicle. This was a team effort, with me
                            being one
                            of the
                            programmers for the project.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Portblock">
                <div class="PortPres">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Portal 2 Custom Map</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortPicBox">
                        <iframe class="PortPic" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r52zQmvZ4L0" frameborder="0"
                            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="PortInfo">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Info on Portal 2 Custom Map</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortExpl">
                        <p>Using Valve's Hammer Editor, I created a custom map for Portal 2 that called for the player
                            to
                            use
                            alternate
                            means to catch objects and to reach different parts of the map. Also made a tutorial on
                            making
                            custom
                            brush
                            shapes within the editor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> -->
            <div class="Portblock">
                <div class="PortPres">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Unreal Target Test</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortPicBox">
                        <iframe class="PortPic" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/itt-z1gIYxY" frameborder="0"
                            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="PortInfo">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Info on Unreal Target Test</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortExpl">
                        <p>Using Unreal Engine Blueprint, I created a target inlineNav map that had parts of the map
                            changing and
                            the
                            targets following a determined path.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Portblock">
                <div class="PortPres">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Rockstar Bully Analysis/Other Blogs</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortPicBox">
                        <iframe class="PortPic"
                            src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQ--lYr9hisdK0AR5Vze8K9hldvgLg6EL8VhxnSyf2KaBBefB7-45DMnSH19fM0jk39mmECs4KTCd1M/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="PortInfo">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Info on Blogs</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortExpl">
                        <p>Studied the design of Bully's tutorial level and broke it down for an audience of possible
                            Game
                            Design
                            Students. Did this for other games as well, such as Don't Starve and Uncharted.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Portblock">
                <div class="PortPres">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Card Mechanics and Art for Bring Them To The Festival</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortPicBox">
                        <img class="PortPicSmall" src="Images/Card1.png">
                        <img class="PortPicSmall" src="Images/Card2.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="PortInfo">
                    <div class="PortObjname">
                        <h2>Info on Card Mechanics and Art</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="PortExpl">
                        <p>Integrated a way to use cards for the Board Game called Bring Them To The Festival. Also,
                            created
                            the
                            card
                            art by using a mixture of Photoshop and Illustrator. Development on Bring Them To The
                            Festival
                            was a
                            team
                            effort, with me being the card artist of the team. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Footer">
        <p class="footinfo">Hakim Ottey © 2019</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `display: none` as a CSS style to the main body, so that it's immediately hidden on page load, and then fading it in when the DOM is ready?

Comment: fubar's suggestions works on my end.